# Android: WebView content is scrolling fast than CollapsingToolBar in Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

In my Android project, I'm trying to use CollapsingToolBar and WebView inside NestedScrollView with a CoordinatorLayout, but I'm facing webview content scrolling fast under AppBar image and not synchronized with AppBar vertical scroll speed when webview content is scrolled quickly.

Below is xml for Coordinator layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff77"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/rabbit"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/article_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please suggest, what is wrong in this layout.
Full Source Code is available at below link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvmqgpgg9e9pqpp/AndroidCoordinatorNestedScrollView.zip?dl=0

Below is the Activity file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class CoordinatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coordinator);
         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         webView = (WebView)  findViewById(R.id.article_webview);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        String html = getResources().getString(R.string.html_story);
        webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help to scroll the webview content with same speed of collapsing image in app bar, currently it scrolls faster with in nestedscrollview.